# How to debug ARCore - AugmentedImage

Tags: android, mobile, augmented-reality, arcore

We are developing an Android mobile app and our goal is to detect and track the top face of an object. We are having some difficulties to perform the detection because the top face of the object is continuously changing because of the shadows.

There is a way to plot live on-screen the cloud of points that the ARCore detection engine is "seeing" ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What is the tracking score of your image from ./arcoreimg eval-img tool?

Comment: We tried with different images and the score is always 100